# Passing param value to selector

Tags: ios, swift

I am declaring a selector and want to pass a label object as the parameter and not able to do so.

**Below is my code:**

```
public func animateLabelText(label: UILabel) {
 caDisplayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(changeLabelText(label: label)))
}

@objc private func changeLabelText(label: UILabel) {
    // Do something
}
```

I am seeing this error - Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer.

How do I pass the parameter to selector?

Comment: Your selector format is wrong, but that's not your whole problem.  Sorry, but you don't get to choose what parameters the called selector take.  In this case, the selector will be passed the `CADisplayLink`.  You can't make it take a label.

Comment: Ok... I will try some different way then to pass the label to this reusable func. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The signature should be as following

```
public func animateLabelText(label: UILabel) {
  caDisplayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, 
                              selector: #selector(changeLabelText(_:)))
}

@objc private func changeLabelText(_ label: UILabel) {
    // Do something
}
```